# Imagehack and paperclip how to create a thumb and define path and filename?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I am trying to create a thumb with and uploaded image. I also want to resize the uploaded image to 672x378 and the thumb is should be 219x123.

The path for the thumb should be photographer/image/:id/thumb:Filename

I have installed imageshack (gem 'Rmagick') and intstalled the program on my pc.

My model:

```
  has_attached_file :image,
    :storage => :s3,
    :bucket => 'mybucket',
    :path => '/photographer/image/:id/:filename',
    :s3_credentials => {
      :access_key_id => 'mykey',
      :secret_access_key => 'mykey'
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to attach images to photographers.  So in that case I would include this code on the photographer model.

```
has_attached_file :image, 
  :styles => {  :original => "672>x378>", :thumb => "219>x123>" }, # width x height
  :storage => :s3,
  :bucket => "mybucket",
  :path => "photographers/:id/images/:style/:basename.:extension",
  :s3_credentials => {
    :access_key_id => 'mykey',
    :secret_access_key => 'mykey'
  }
```

Not that the `>` after the size of the images will restrict the width from exceeding the value, but still keep the image in proportion. So, the image can't go larger than the height or width.  You can remove those if you want.

Comment: Would it resize and create the images. Example if I upload an image with a size of 900x800?

Comment: Yes.. Also, here are the different settings you can use when trying to figure out the sizes you want: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php#geometry

Comment: With an image of 900x800, you will end up with an "original" at 672x597, and a "thumb" at 219x195. If you want it to be exactly what you've specified, i'd suggest cropping it to the same aspect ratio that you want then resizing.

Comment: I have just tried your answer and uploaded a image it create this path: photographers/images/62/thumb/myimage.jpg and photographers/images/62/orginal/myimage.jpg instead of photographers/images/62/myimage.jpg and photographers/images/62/thumbmyimage.jpg

Comment: ok, yeah I was just assuming that is how you would want the path.. if not then change path to :path => "photographers/images/:id/:style/:basename.:extension", or you can remove the :style to put them in the same id folder.